# Difference between "click" and onclick

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between click in

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate);
```

and onclick in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 onclick="this.innerHTML='Ooops!'">Click on this text!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Are they both considered as events? Why can't we use click instead of onclick and visce versa?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, they are both events, simply put the same, and one use `onclick` when assign its handler *inline*, and the other `click` when assign using an *event listener* (which is the recommended way).

And you can't use them vice versa, as this is how it has to be done or they won't work.

Read more at MDN:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers

Answer (score 19):

The difference is that the first (`click`) is an [event listener](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener), and the second (`onclick`) is an [event handler content attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes).

Event handler content attributes store an [internal raw uncompiled handler](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler), which produces an event listener via the [event handler processing](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm) and [getting the current value of the event handler](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#getting-the-current-value-of-the-event-handler) algorithms.

In practice, this affects the scope, e.g.

```
(function() { var element = document.body;
  var str = "console.log([typeof foo, typeof bar])";
  var func = function() { console.log([typeof foo, typeof bar]); };
  element.foo = 'foo';
  var bar = 'bar';
  element.setAttribute('onclick', str);
  element.addEventListener('click', func);
  element.click();
  // Event handler content attribute logs ["string", "undefined"]
  // Event listener logs ["undefined", "string"]
})();
```

I discourage using event handlers. They are an old reminiscence and are superseded by event listeners.

Comment: Can you please refer to these by their names instead of first and second? A reader can get confused scrolling up and down to check which came first, and still not be certain that they are interpreting them correctly.

Comment: Pointing out a problem regarding event handlers being _an old reminiscence superseded by event listeners:_ event listeners are imperatively linked (usually via some lookup, frequently aided by adding extraneous attributes), they're invisible on the DOM, and can't be rewired by editing an attribute on a live HTML document. This does not a replacement make.

Answer (score -3):

```
$("#profile-register #submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("I executed")
    })
```

successfully prevent the default the behavior,but code below can't

```
$("#profile-register #submit").onclick=function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("I executed")
    }
```

it redirect the form with parameter,you can see it in the URL frame above