# What's the difference between .click() and .onclick() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, click

What's the difference between

```
document.getElementById("id").click();
```

and

```
document.getElementById("id").onclick();
```

?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960241/difference-between-click-and-onclick

Comment: @rene: No, not if you read that closely.

Answer (score 13):

`click` is a function on HTML elements you can call to trigger their click handlers: `element.click();`

`onclick` is a property that reflects the `onclick` attribute and allows you to attach a "DOM0" handler to the element for when clicks occur: `element.onclick = function() { /*...*/};` (The modern equivalent is `addEventListener("click", ...)` [or `attachEvent` on obsolete versions of IE].) If you *called* `onclick` (`element.onclick()`), you'd call the function attached to it — but not handlers attached with modern methods.

E.g., `click` triggers a fake click; the other lets you set up a handler for clicks. (If you *call* `onclick`, it'll only call the handler attached via that old DOM0 mechanism.)

Example:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("input[type=button]");
// Add a modern handler to it
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Modern handler called");
});
// Add an obsolete DOM0 handler to it
btn.onclick = function() {
  console.log("DOM0 handler called");
};
// Call `click`
console.log("Calling click():");
btn.click();
// Call `onclick` (which would be VERY unusual)
console.log("Calling onclick():");
btn.onclick();
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
```

Comment: `onclick` is a property so it should be accessed as `document.getElementById("id").onclick`, right? Won't `document.getElementById("id").onclick()` call the returned function? The behavior *might* be different though.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Yes, it would. I'll clarify.

Comment: Also, won't `this` be different in both the cases? In `click()` it will be the object on which the handler is attached. In `onclick()` it would be a normal function call and `this` would be inherited from the calling context. (I am not sure about this).

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: *"it would be a normal function call and this would be inherited from the calling context"* That's not how `this` works. More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work (And no, `this` would be the same in both cases, provided the functio[s] being called aren't bound or arrow functions.)

Comment: Thanks! I was unsure about the case.