# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression in onClick method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

when i write this code

```
<Button click={() => 
             { props.hide; props.history.push('/checkout'); }} >Go To CHECKOUT</Button>
```

it gives me that error Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

what should i do ?

Comment: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36960277/463206) that says " one use onclick when assign its handler inline, and the other click when assign using an event listener ... And you can't use them vice versa, as this is how it has to be done or they won't work."

Answer (score 1):

Your function body contains an expression that is not assigned or invoked.

```
function anon() {
  props.hide; // The engine will evaluate this and then...do nothing with it
  // The warning is saying you probably meant props.hide()
  // or const fn = props.hide
  props.history.push();
}
```

BTW it might help to write at most one expression per line so you can easily see where the error is coming from.

```
<Button click={() => {
  props.hide();
  props.history.push('/checkout');
}}>
  {"Go To CHECKOUT"}
</Button>
```

Comment: hide is coming from redux

Comment: Ok. Write `props.hide()` instead of `props.hide` and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try onClick instead of click.

Comment: it's a custom button

Comment: What does the code for the custom button look like?

Comment: ``` const Button = props => (
    <button className={` ${props.inverted ? 'inverted' : ''} custom-button ${props.isGoogleSignIn ? 'google-sign-in' : ''} custom-button`} onClick={props.click} value={props.value}>
        {props.children}

    </button>
) ```