# addeventlistener("onClick") is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm coding a simple app to add itens to a shopping bag to study Javascript. However my js code didn't register when the element is clicked, it's not printing on console.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    //your code here
    const fruitList = [{
            'fruit': 'Banana',
            'price': 3.9
        },
        {
            'fruit': 'Orange',
            'price': 0.7
        },

    ]

    const product = document.getElementById('products')
    ListaFrutas.map((n) => {
        product.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<li class="fruits">' + n.fruit + '</li>');
    })

    const shoppingBag = []
    const fruitproduct = document.querySelector('.fruits')
    fruitproduct.addEventListener("onClick", handlerClick)

    function handlerClick() {
        console.log('it works')
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="content-produtos" class="flex" >
  <ul id="produtos" >
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The code shown won't even get to the `addEventListener` because it fails when trying to use `ListaFrutas` which is not defined.

Comment: Also your retreiving an element by the ID `products` but your HTML has the ID `produtos`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `LitsaFrutas` is defined elsewhere, you should replace "onClick" with "click".

```
addEventListener("click", handlerClick);
```

See also: [Difference between "click" and onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960241/difference-between-click-and-onclick)